# Model Collection.php magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, resource-model

I cant seem to find any information why we need to create a Collection.php file inside ResourceModel and what is the purpose of collection.

Comment: The collection model is considered a resource model which allow us to filter and fetch a collection table data.

Answer (score 0):

With a model and resource model, you are having everything that you need/want to fetch and save from/into the database.

However, there will be some situation when you’ll require to fetch multiple models of a particular type. To solve this problem, every CRUD model in **Magento 2** has a corresponding resource model collection.

A collection collects individual models. It’s considered as a resource model because it builds the SQL code which required to pull the information from a database table.

For more information you can refer [this site](https://belvg.com/blog/database-in-magento-2-models-resource-models-and-collections.html)